# Context Free capable of generating all regular languages?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

I am currently studying Theory of Computation where i came across a statement, "
CFG may also create Regular language " or it should be All CFG can create all (any) regular languages

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a language question than it is a Computer Science question. That said, here's what may be a more clear formulation of what I think is trying to be conveyed:

> For any regular language, there is a context-free grammar that generates that regular language.

To see this, we may first construct a canonical context-free grammar for the regular language. We might take a right-regular grammar as the canonical CFG for a RL. I won't go into details about that construction but it assumes a DFA for the language is known and produces a CFG whose productions mirror transitions in the automaton.

Given the existence of a single CFG for any RL, we immediately have that there are infinitely many equivalent CFGs for any RL.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, REG is a subset of CF. Thus clearly every regular language is also context-free and can be generated by a CFG.